# Resource is out of sync error after adding Google Play Services Library to Project

Tags: google-maps, google-play-services

I'm having some trouble in a project that uses Google Maps Android API v2.

I'm trying to debug an example project following the Maps API 2 Official tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=pt-PT

Everything was working well, but when I added the Google Play Services Library to the
project, just as following this tutorial:
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

I received the following error:

`> Unable to create editor ID org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PropertiesFileEditor: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/tnc/project.properties'.`

The error happens when I add the library (`.jar`) file to the project.
When I remove the library file everything goes back to normal.

I don't understand why adding the library invalidates my `project.properties` file.
I've tried everything: refreshing, *Android Tools* -> *Fix Project Properties*
but I can't fix the error. One red exclamation point appears in the project folder icon when the error occurs.